# Is there a way to iterate through a heap in its heap order without popping?

Tags: c++, heap

If I make a heap and iterate through it, it doesn't show it in the right order:

```
vector<int> q;
q.push_back(3);
q.push_back(7);
q.push_back(5);
make_heap(q.begin(), q.end());

for (auto it = q.begin(); it != q.end(); ++it) {
    cout << *it << " ";
}
```

Outputs:

```
7 3 5
```

When I want

```
7 5 3
```

I know I can simply pop off the max each time. But what if don't want to pop anything off?

Comment: The heap isn't *in* 'its heap order'. It is only partially ordered. Popping it provides the total ordering. You can't do this.

Comment: Binary heaps (heap made by std::make_heap) are NOT already sorted after construction. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap for a great reference on how binary heaps work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a heap is not fully sorted. Popping is the operation that sorts the heap, if you will.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method is to duplicate the entire heap, then pop elements from it. I don't think you could do it without a second heap, because at any given point in time, you need the minimum element of a "wavefront" of possible next elements that moves down from the top of the heap -- and that wavefront needs to have elements selected in order of minimum (or maximum) value.